# On dropdown select viewbag data get changed but the view displays old data

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

My drop down where I am getting my groupId

```
  <select id="GroupDropdown" name="GroupDropdown" onchange="Filteration();" class="form-control"></select>
```

MY Javascript ajax

```
 function Filteration()
{
    var groupid = document.getElementById("GroupDropdown").value;
    var subgroupid = document.getElementById("SubGroupDropdown").value;
    var locationid = document.getElementById("LocationID").value;
    var propertyname = document.getElementById("txtPropertyName").value;
    var propertydescription = document.getElementById("Description").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Home/Index",
        data: { 'GroupId': groupid, 'SubGroupId': subgroupid, 'LocationId': locationid, 'PropertyName': propertyname, 'Description': propertydescription},
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);               
        },
        error: function (request) {               
        }
    });
}
```

Hi in my controller I had written a code which every time I get new data according to GroupId and other data pass.

```
  public ActionResult Index(string GroupId, string SubGroupId, string LocationId, string PropertyName, string Description)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsUpsDelTbl_Property"))
            {
                try
                {
                    DataSet GetData = new DataSet();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operation", "GetPropertyDataFilteration");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupID", GroupId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubGroupID", SubGroupId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", LocationId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", PropertyName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    ad.Fill(GetData);                       
                    ViewBag.tblProperty = GetData.Tables[1];
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { throw ex; }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Here in above code on basis of groupid, subgroupid the data of ViewBag.tblProperty get changed but the data displaying on view is not changing. The view is displaying same data retrieved initially from viewbag.tblProperty when page get loads for the 1st time.

My view page code

```
 @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tblProperty.Rows)
    {          
       <p><b>Group:</b> @dr["GroupName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>SubGroup:</b> @dr["SubGroupName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>Location:</b> @dr["LocationName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>Age:</b> @dr["Age"].ToString() Years</p> 
    }
```

initially on page load event the group id, subgroup id is used to pass as empty so at that time 4 data used to get retrieved from database and used to get that data bind in viewbag.tblProperty but after changing of group id, subgroup id data only 2 data gets retrieved from database and viewbag.tblProperty again get bind with that data but on view page same old record with 4 data is used to display.

How can I change the view on basis of data retrieved from database

Comment: Did the browser cache the page?

Comment: @jasen No I don't think so

Comment: @Jasen Hi I had reviewed the logic and had found that the data frm controller side to view is coming proper but as I am calling this passing data through ajax the page does not get refresh and because of that the view is not binding properly. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you change your dropdown, you are calling the `Filteration` javascript method which does an ajax call. In your action method, you are setting the viewbag and returning the view. But your original razor view code was already executed and the output of which you are currently seeing in your browser).

You have 2 options.

**1. Do not use ajax call. Reload the GET action**

So instead of making the ajax call, you make a normal HTTP request to the GET action method with the selected values as querystring params. With your current action method code, it sets the viewbag data and return the view. When razor executes the code it will render the new data in the viewBag.

```
function Filteration()
{
    var groupid = $("#GroupDropdown").val();
    var subgroupid = $("#SubGroupDropdown").val();
    var locationid = $("#LocationID").val();
    var propertyname = $("#txtPropertyName").val();
    var propertydescription = $("#Description").val();

    var baseUrl="/Home/Index?groupId="+groupId+"&subgroupid="+subgroupid+
                   "&locationId="+locationid+"&propertyname="+propertyname+
                   "&propertydescription"=propertydescription ;
    window.location.href=baseUrl; 
}
```

**2. Use ajax, but have the action method return partial view result.**

Have your action method return a partial view result for ajax call. So create a partial view and return that when the request is an ajax call and update the DOM of current page when you receive the successful response from the ajax call.

So create a partial view called `ResultList` and it will have this code

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tblProperty.Rows)
{          
       <p><b>Group:</b> @dr["GroupName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>SubGroup:</b> @dr["SubGroupName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>Location:</b> @dr["LocationName"].ToString()</p>
       <p><b>Age:</b> @dr["Age"].ToString() Years</p>
```

}

and your action method return this partial view

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
   return PartialView("ResultList");
}
return View();
```

Now go to the main view and replace the loop code with a call to the partial and wrap it inside a container div.

```
<div id="results">
   @Html.Partial("ResultList")
</div>
```

Now on your ajax call's success/done event, update the content of this container div with the results coming from the ajax call.

```
success: function (data) {
       $("#results").html(data);             
},
```

Comment: my late reply but I will try it today and let u know

Comment: can u get me some example working like this, so that I can understand the proper flow?